# Sum with different condition from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a timeRanges table, which is like

```
+---+------------------+------------------+
|   | FromTime         | ToTime.          |
+---+------------------+------------------+
| 1 | 06:00:00.0000000 | 08:00:00.0000000 |
| 2 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 09:00:00.0000000 |
| 3 | 09:00:00.0000000 | 17:00:00.0000000 |
| 4 | 17:00:00.0000000 | 20:00:00.0000000 |
+---+------------------+------------------+
```

Furthermore, several raw data as below

```
+---+-------------------------+-------+--------+
|   | Time                    | Value | Member |
+---+-------------------------+-------+--------+
| 1 | 2019-10-11 06:18:29.000 | 10000 | 000001 |
| 2 | 2019-10-11 07:10:10.000 | 20000 | 000001 |
| 3 | 2019-10-12 08:30:20.000 | 30000 | 000002 |
| 4 | 2019-10-12 15:16:29.000 | 50000 | 000001 |
| 5 | 2019-11-13 18:00:29.000 | 70000 | 000002 |
| 6 | 2019-11-13 19:18:29.000 | 60000 | 000002 |
+---+-------------------------+-------+--------+
```

I am trying to sum several data in different time ranges every day.
 Row1 and Row2 are in 06:00~08:00 that they need to be calculated together.

The result I expected:

```
+---+-------------------------+-------+--------+
|   | Time                    | Value | Member |
+---+-------------------------+-------+--------+
| 1 | 2019-10-11 06:00:00.000 | 30000 | 000001 |
| 2 | 2019-10-12 08:00:00.000 | 30000 | 000002 |
| 3 | 2019-10-12 09:00:00.000 | 50000 | 000001 |
| 4 | 2019-11-13 17:00:00.000 | 130000| 000002 |
+---+-------------------------+-------+--------+
```

Can someone give me a keyword to reach it? I have tried to use partition by but it's noting like I want.

Updated:
I would like to put raw data into the result with time bindings.

Comment: Please do include what you tried in your question. Thanks. Guessing you're trying to put them into hour bandings here?

Comment: `SUM()` with Group by `Member` and `Time`?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work. I've left the date and the time split in the final results but if you need to match your final requirements exactly it shouldn't be too hard to combine them.

```
With TimeRanges AS
(
SELECT ID
, CAST(FromTime AS TIME(0)) AS FromTime
, CAST(ToTime AS TIME(0)) AS ToTime
FROM (VALUES 
 ( 1,  '06:00:00.0000000' , '08:00:00.0000000' )
,( 2,  '08:00:00.0000000' , '09:00:00.0000000' )
,( 3,  '09:00:00.0000000' , '17:00:00.0000000' )
,( 4,  '17:00:00.0000000' , '20:00:00.0000000' )) AS T(ID,FromTime,ToTime)
),
RawData AS
(
SELECT ID,CAST(Time as datetime2(0)) AS Time,Value,Member
FROM (VALUES
 ( 1 , '2019-10-11 06:18:29.000',10000,'000001' )
,( 2 , '2019-10-11 07:10:10.000',20000,'000001' )
,( 3 , '2019-10-12 08:30:20.000',30000,'000002' )
,( 4 , '2019-10-12 15:16:29.000',50000,'000001' )
,( 5 , '2019-11-13 18:00:29.000',70000,'000002' )
,( 6 , '2019-11-13 19:18:29.000',60000,'000002' )
) AS V(ID,Time,Value,Member)
)
SELECT 
CAST(RD.Time as date) AS DataDate
,TR.FromTime
,SUM(RD.Value) AS Value
,RD.Member
FROM RawData AS RD
INNER JOIN TimeRanges AS TR
    ON CAST(RD.Time as time(0)) between TR.FromTime and TR.ToTime
GROUP BY
CAST(RD.Time as date)
,TR.FromTime
,RD.Member
```

Comment: seems "CAST(RD.Time as time(0))" is what I want. I'll try it. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Inner join is your friend here:

```
SELECT ranges.FromTime,
       ranges.ToTime,
       sum(raw.value),
       raw.member
FROM timeRanges ranges
INNER JOIN raw
           ON convert(time, raw.time) between ranges.FromTime and ranges.ToTime
GROUP BY raw.member,
         ranges.fromtime,
         ranges.totime
```

EXAMPLE:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b3d6/5